# Gnome suggests me to open external HDDs with Anjuta

Tags: gnome-shell, external-hdd

When I attach an external HDD, GNOME suggests opening it with Anjuta:

[image: Gnome notification for inserting new HDD]

How can I make it open with Nautilus instead?

Comment: From google, I've tried to  

$xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory

But this changed nothing.

Comment: Why is it a problem that Gnome suggests to use Ajunta?

Comment: @don_crissti please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely it has to do with this commit:

[Open a directory with Anjuta](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2013-January/msg04912.html)

where they changed:

```
 [File Loader]
-SupportedMimeTypes=application/x-anjuta-old
+SupportedMimeTypes=application/x-anjuta-old,inode/directory
```

so when installing `anjuta`, `update-desktop-database` is run (during *post-install*); that updates `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` and the default handler for `inode/directory` becomes `anjuta`.
To fix this run:

```
xdg-mime default org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop inode/directory
```

or manually edit `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and add `inode/directory=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` under `[Default Applications]` e.g:

```
[Default Applications]
inode/directory=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
```

or if you already have an entry for `inode/directory`, make sure `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` is the first in the list.

---

The command (that you had tried)

```
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory
```

no longer works with newer versions of `gnome`/`nautilus` because the (`gnome`) apps are launched using [`D-BUS` activation](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/DBusApplicationLaunching). As a result, `nautilus.desktop` no longer exists - it has been replaced by `org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`

---

If editing `mimeapps.list` has no effect that means [your DE isn't *freedesktop.org* compliant](https://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html) so maybe it's time to file a bug report.

Comment: You might be able to check which way works (or how new your gnome is), by having a look in `ls /usr/share/applications | grep nautilus`

Comment: in some cases (like in my Manjaro), where there is no `mimeapps.list` in `usr/share/applications`, creating one in `~/.local/share/applications` as you indicate will not fix it, but a `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` will do the trick, with that `inode/directory` line under `[MIME Cache]`, as indicated [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336984/32012), following your comment thereunder.