# Changing default file manager in Gnome3 (Fedora 22)

Tags: gnome3, file-manager

I just switched to Fedora 22 and decided to go for Gnome3 this time instead of XFCE. I like the `Thunar` file manager so I downloaded it. I've had trouble setting it as the default file manager though.

**What I tried:**

I ran `exo-preferred-applications`. Under `Utilities -> File Manager` I selected `Thunar`.

**The problem:**

It's not acting as the default file manager. When I open my `Downloads` folder from my browser I still get `Nautilus`. Same when I click on my `"Places"`.

Comment: related: [Gnome suggests me to open external HDDs with Anjuta](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197064)

Comment: No GUI option to perform this?  I fail to find one with Gnome 3.26.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try editing `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` and changing the line

```
inode/directory=nemo.desktop;caja.desktop;nautilus.desktop;Thunar.desktop;kde4-dolphin.desktop
```

to

```
inode/directory=Thunar.desktop;
```

or some order that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately there is not `defaults.list` in my `/usr/share/applications`. Is that normal?

Comment: Every distro is different, but you can try finding it with `$ locate defaults.list`.

Comment: In Debian Jessie no such file is existing.

Answer (score 7):

In Fedora 25, the appropriate file is `/usr/share/applications/gnome-mimeapps.list`. Change the `inode/directory` entry to point to your file manager of choice. Change takes place immediately and the Places menu opens the newly selected application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Interesting about Fedora 25. Thanks.