# follow-up question about replacing Nautilus with Thunar in Fedora 25

Tags: fedora

re [Changing default file manager in Gnome3 (Fedora 22)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206406/changing-default-file-manager-in-gnome3-fedora-22/206411#206411?newreg=c17b3d862d8646c9979ff11697fecb00)

when i try to edit gnome-mimeapps.list i get this:

```
[d@d-HP-Pavilion-dv6700-Notebook-PC ~]$ sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/gnome-mimeapps.list 
[sudo] password for d: 
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:2969): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

**??**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sudo gedit`. It will change to different user (`root`) and then try to open you a graphical window. This worked find with older versions, because they were using old X11, but it does not work with Wayland, because it is very bad security practice to mix processes ran by different users in a single graphical session.

Just use some command-line editor such as `vim` or `nano`.

Comment: i cant type and even if i could, i can't remember all those elliptical things.  i moved from Xubu to Fed because that Gnu chap said he reckons its the most functional (and so far, i agree, except bluetooth doesnt work), but surely things have moved on since Unix was invented?  maybe not.  anyhow, i've decided to rewrite the entire disk, just to get rid of a few bytes at the front that get in the way and make grub-rescue go into a spin i cant get out of because it wont listen to anything i type, like exit/quit/stop/go away/ etc (and Fedora tells me there's no such thing as grub-rescue!)

Comment: This does not look related to the original question.