# "Open Containing Folder" not using the file manager

Tags: ubuntu, elementary-os, browser

When I download anything using Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox and I use the "Show in folder" option (or "Open Containing Folder" in case of Firefox) it does not work correctly, instead, it open the directory with my text editor Atom...

What I can do to make it work properly?

**PS**: My OS is Elementary.

Comment: what is your default file manager ? could you  run "nautilus" command in terminal

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me even in other programs like uGet, a downloader that also has the option "open containing folder".

The problem is, as indicated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197157/32012) triggered by the certain programs.

The best solution is to create or edit `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`: edit the line that starts with `inode/directory=` and add the name of the file manager that you use if it is not there already; if that is already there but another program is listed there first, **put the file manager first** (if you need the other program(s) to open folders).

For Pantheon Files it should be like

```
[Default Applications]
inode/directory=org.pantheon.files.desktop;
```

If the desktop environment is not freedesktop complient, like my Manjaro Cinnamon, the file to be created/edited should be `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` like so:

```
[MIME Cache]
inode/directory=org.pantheon.files.desktop;
```

---

You should post elementaryOS questions on its own stackexchange site: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/