# Set standard file browser for "open containing folder"

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, nautilus, file-manager

Since I installed EasyTag on my Arch Linux several other programs use EasyTag instead of Nautilus as filebrowser.

For example, Firefox starts EasyTag if I click on "open containing folder".

Where can I set Nautilus as my "standard file browser"?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Gnome suggests me to open external HDDs with Anjuta](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197064)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can define the default file browser by editing the file `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. Open this file and change the line `inode/directory` as follow

```
inode/directory=nautilus.desktop;
```

If this doesn't work, you should change the filemanager in the file

```
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
```

by adding (or updating) this line

```
inode/directory=nautilus.desktop
```

Comment: Yeah looks like easytag corrupted the inode/diectoryline in mimeinfo.cache: 
inode/directory=easytag.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
Was able to fix it, thx!

Comment: It depends on factors that I cannot state, but in some cases the file manager only needs to be present (mentioned) after `inode/directory=`, even on the last position, *no matter if others are also listed there and in what order*. In case it doesn't work, one should try to put it there *first*, while keeping others. If this still doesn't work, it may be necessary to remove at least the culprit that takes over if not all other programs mentioned there except the file manager.

Comment: @iBlink - multiple programs listed there shouldn't be a problem, but sometimes is. Have you tried by just putting nautilus *first*? -- Keeping other programs there (like easytag or media players) may be useful as it adds them to the 'open with' context menu as an option for folders

Comment: @cipricus Ah multiple lines are for the open as context menu? Nice to knew since easytag somehow overwrites my changes all the time. I just add another line with inode/directory. Thanks

Comment: How to avoid the problem entirely: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/336982/32012

Comment: @iBlink - I have found new info on this problem. See my link above.

Comment: `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` is deprecated and not used by Firefox. You should edit `~/.config/mimeapps.list`. For more hierarchy information it's best to refer directly to here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_applications

Answer (score 7):

The following command solved this problem in arch linux:

```
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory
```

(Source: [Arch Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=166366))

Comment: In my case the cache was the problem so I edited the file  `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` "with sudo"

Answer (score 5):

You can find a comprehensive description of setting up [default applications here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_applications) in the according Arch wiki article.

For your specific case, you edit `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and add a new line with `inode/directory=nautilus.desktop` to the section `[Default Applications]`.

The file should look similar to the following one:

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=SciTE.desktop 
text/x-tex=texmaker.desktop 
inode/directory=nautilus.desktop
```

Comment: That worked form me I could't find the folder in the accepted answer

Comment: The file ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` is deprecated (I posted a comment about that to the accepted answer).

Answer (score 2):

Use `env XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=10 xdg-mime query default inode/directory` to get the full list of queried files. You'll get an output like this:

```
Checking ~/.config/mimeapps.list
Checking ~/.local/share/applications/gnome-defaults.list and ~/.local/share/applications/gnome-mimeinfo.cache
Checking ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list and ~/.local/applications/mimeinfo.cache
nautilus.desktop
```

Check each of these files.